# Different processor information using Memtest86+

Tags: grub2, memtest86+

I just checked my system's RAM using Memtest86+ but it shows a different processor information Intel core i7 but actually it is Intel® Pentium(R) CPU G3240 @ 3.10GHz dual core.Why there is different processor information when I use Memtest86+ to check my System's RAM?

Comment: Use the latest version of memtest86+ and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: The newest Memtest86+ was released on August 5, 2016 and the G3240 came out in 2014. How old is your Memtest86+?

Comment: What makes you think you had a 4th Generation Core I7?  Have you used something other then Memtest86+ to verify the results your getting?

Comment: It really doesn't matter. Memtest is for testing RAM not identifying a CPU